# How to Export the UV Map of a Cycled Hair Mesh?

Tags: uv, particles, hair, normal-map

I'm currently working on a Sims 4 Custom Content Hair Mesh, and Here's what it looks like;

[image: This is the closest thing I can do to make a certain hairstyle for a mod...]

Anyway, I'm not trying to create a rendered image, I'm trying to create a UV Map so I can recolor the hair and Import the said colored texture into Sims 4 Studio...
I need help, for I am not that skilled in Blender, and I learned all of the mesh making process from a tutorial... If anyone at all can help me, that would be REALLY appreciated... And sadly, if I ask more questions, I'm sorry in advance... And BTW, I'm using Blender 2.70, for it is the only one that will work with S4S...
Please help me...
Thank you very much!

-SK289

Answer (score 0):

[image]u must select desired object (with a finished UV), then creat material and create image texture node in it, then in UV/Image editor creat image with resolution what you need and indicate this image in texture node, then select texture node (so that it is highlighted with a yellow frame) and in the render tab choose Bake -> BakeType: UV -> Press Bake Button